# Add business hours field to account record page

Tags: custom-field

I have a request to add business hours field to account record page. This should look something like this [image]

Is this going to be a custom component on the account record page? Any other ways we can do this?

Comment: Do you mean business hours for each account record?  Not the business hours for the company that is running this Salesforce instance?  Regardless, you'll need a custom component.  Though a screen flow might work too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Business hours are configurable at the [company level for a salesforce instance](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.customize_supporthours.htm&type=5), not at the account level, which is available in the setup > Company Settings > Business hours.

If you are looking to set business hours for each account (wherever applicable) , you got two options:

1. Have 21 fields, 3 for each day of the week, in account object. i.e. Day_of_week, FromTime, ToTime. ( this solution nifty and simple but limited to scalability).
2. Have a custom object as a child of account, and define your desired fields in that object. You can have the related list under account page layout to display records like you need (This is more scalable).

P.S. Both of the solution mentioned above are standard point-and-click and do not require a custom development (custom component).

Comment: Awesome Mahmood. Thanks for the detailed explanation.